PHP crypt() function behavior / security concern - is that a php bug?
working with crypt() function, I can observe that :
$var1 = crypt('rasmuslerdorf', 'cd');
$var2 = crypt('rasmuslerdorfWhatever', 'cd');

generates exactly the same output ! Here : cdqYxeZGYiRPw
You can try by yourself online : https://fr.functions-online.com/crypt.html
From the doc I can read about the maximum length of the resulting string, but nothing about the input string !

Returns the hashed string or a string that is shorter than 13 characters and is guaranteed to differ from the salt on failure.

Is that a normal behavior ? I don't think so.
I'm using PHP Version 8.1.2 // same behavior observed on PHP7.4.16

This is not my area of expertise, but according to this, traditional DES truncates down to eight characters, and according to the docs, a two character salt kicks in standard DES, which I assume is the same as “traditional”. So from your example, you can drop even more characters: https://3v4l.org/oL8jG
